# OpenLayers Clustering Adds Features to Selected Features Array on Zoom

Tags: openlayers-2, clustering

This is my first posted question despite using StackExchange for a few years now. I've been stuck for quite some time trying to figure out this issue with OpenLayers. The problem is as follows:

I have a bunch of features plotted on a map and am able to select features in various ways (e.g. drawing a box around them, clicking on individual features, entering a zip code that selects all features within that zip code, etc.). This all works fine. The issue is that I have a clustering strategy on the features layer and when I zoom out, currently selected features get clustered together with unselected features and those unselected features will become selected when I zoom back in. What I'm trying to accomplish is to NOT have the previously unselected features become selected after clustering.

Here is a link to a visual hosted on my website (http://korynorthrop.com/uploads/Visual.jpg) I could post some code as well, but thought I'd simplify this question first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My inclination before posting this question was to just track the selected features outside of OpenLayers and reselect them after the zoom event. I couldn't come up with another solution and this method worked for what I needed it to do.